# Listing scheduled automatic updates

Tags: windows-7, auto-updates

In windows 7, the shutdown button shows the shield when it must execute an automatic udpate.

How can I list the automatic updates that the system will execute?

I need to know what are the update packages that will be executed before having them installed.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Windows Update UI and look at the list of pending updates.

For more info on accessing the Windows Update UI see: [Install Windows updates in Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows7/install-windows-updates)

Comment: In the windows update UI there isn't a "pending changes" option. On the left I see: "check for updates" "change settings" "view update history" "restore hidden updates" "Updates: frequently asked questions". Then on the right I see "Updates are available for your computer" where I can select or de-select the updates I want to install choosing from the important or optional updates. The last time the shield appeared on the shutdown button, both lists where empty.